# Getting the last non-nan index of a sorted numpy matrix or pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a numpy array (or pandas dataframe) like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
[1,      1,      1,    0.5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
[1,      1,      1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
[1,      1,      1,    0.5,   0.25,  0.125,  0.075],
[1,      1,      1,   0.25, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
[1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
[1,      1,    0.5,    0.5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
])
```

I'm looking to most efficiently retrieve the last non-nan value in each row, so in this situation I'd be looking for a function that returns something like this:

```
np.array([3,
          2,
          6,
          3,
          0,
          3])
```

I can try `np.argmin(a, axis=1) - 1`, but this has at least two undesirable properties - it fails for rows not ending with `nan` (dealbreaker) and it doesn't "lazy-evaluate" and stop once it has reached the last non-nan value in a given row (this doesn't matter as much as the "it has to be right" condition).

I imagine there's a way to do it with `np.where`, but in addition to evaluating all the elements of each row, I can't see an obvious elegant way to rearrange the output to get the last index in each row:

```
>>> np.where(np.isnan(a))
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]),
 array([4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pandas.Series has a `last_valid_index` method:

```
pd.DataFrame(a.T).apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index)
Out: 
0    3
1    2
2    6
3    3
4    0
5    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 7):

This solution doesn't require the array to be sorted.  It just returns the last non nan item along axis 1.

```
(~np.isnan(a)).cumsum(1).argmax(1)
```

Answer (score 4):

check if not nan then reverse order of columns and take argmax then subtract from number of columns

```
a.shape[1] - (~np.isnan(a))[:, ::-1].argmax(1) - 1

array([3, 2, 6, 3, 0, 3])
```

Comment: The implementation of last_valid_index is very similar to this one. I tried adapting but failed.

Answer (score 3):

If all `nan` values have been sorted to the end of each row, you can do something like this:

```
(~np.isnan(a)).sum(axis = 1) - 1
# array([3, 2, 6, 3, 0, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Well here is a way to do it. Probably not the most efficient though:

```
list(map(lambda x: [i for i, x_ in enumerate(x) if not np.isnan(x_)][-1], a))
```

Also it will fail if any row is fully 'nan' because python will try to do `getitem` on an empty list.