# How to find the last valid value's index in list or array

Tags: python, list, nan

I would like to find the last valid value.
I found some code for dataframe but can't find for the code for list or array

```
List = [nan, 1, 4, 6, 8, 122, 12, 34, 54, nan, nan, nan,nan, nan]
```

The result should look like this:

```
print(some_function_for_last_valid_index(List))
output : 8
```

(output is an index)

Comment: so should the first `nan` be ignored in `List`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the last non-nan index of a sorted numpy matrix or pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41111052/getting-the-last-non-nan-index-of-a-sorted-numpy-matrix-or-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: you mean the last non "nan" value ?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one approach

**Ex:**

```
import numpy as np
lst = [np.nan, 1, 4, 6, 8, 122, 12, 34, 54, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan, np.nan]
lst = [i for i in lst if not np.isnan(i)]
#or lst = filter(lambda x: np.isfinite(x), lst)
print(len(lst)) #8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter out all nan values and then return the last item. To achieve it you can use build-in function `filter`

```
new_list = list(fileter(lambda x: x != 'nan', old_list))
print(new_list[-1])
```

But I don't know why in your example you expect output to be `7`.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. The output should be 8 not 7

Comment: Still, don't get it... The output should be the last valid item or number of correct items in the list?

Comment: You cant filter out all nan values, in this case he want to keep nan at position List[0]

Answer (score 2):

```
nan = 'nan'
List = [nan, 1, 4, 6, 8, 122, 12, 34, 54, nan, nan, nan,nan, nan]

for i in range(len(List)-1,0,-1):
    if List[i] != nan:
        print(i)
        break
```

outpout:

```
8
```

another solution:

```
while List and List[-1] is nan: List.pop()
print(len(List)-1)
```

outpout:

```
8
```